# Typescript, cleaner way to target a generic class method

Tags: typescript

Let's consider the following code:

```js
export class BaseClass<T> {
  property = this.buildProperty();

  buildProperty(){
    return someBuilder<T>();
  }
}
```

TS will magically infer the type of `property` using the returned type of `buildProperty()`

Now for a cleaner code, I would like to build the property within the constructor, I refactored the code [as follows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEGcEsBtoT1AMwK4DsDGAXSB7VoAnAU02QNUlQHNQBDUAE0kUSONU1EzgAciuAFkXwAVUAAohxUACtk4TmIA+AAoUFKNRDgKD+RAB60Atj2hEAlACgUGbHgg5jRAELIYDNgB4RAPnEWAFygyhCYGtQA3laghCRk+JEAvnTgoGgA1qg4AO74tGmh6poA3FZJVlaGPDqc6NAFaS4FRADCDeDgPr6g0bE8BDh8BNzBAErx5CK8RF7N4G0dXX4A2gDkAEbu0AwACoPD3GsAur5lMaDoeOrIWDoBfbGCkOAAdANDbNygALzPb1sPPtPiM4AEyrEKhdATtgYcwRZHrFiKRyI5nG4PN4-OCLhUoVdUAouERiX9UEQcqB5otGl5UMhjBs2P4LGVMKTMO8Dl8ECBQC9QAymWxQEowhEqEA):

```js
export class BaseClass<T> {
  property: ReturnType<BaseClass<T>['buildProperty']>;

  constructor(){
    this.property = this.buildProperty();
  }

  buildProperty(){
    return someBuilder<T>();
  }
}
```

Which is correct, however I'm not satisfied in repeating the current class type twice i.e. `BaseClass<T>`

I am then wondering if I could simplify the line using `this`. I tried rewriting the property's type as follow but had no success:

```js
property: ReturnType<this['buildProperty']>;
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can simply use `ReturnType<typeof this.buildProperty>`

```js
// silly function returning a different type then T (here just T | string for the example)
function someBuilder<T>(): T | string{
  return {} as unknown as T | string;
}

export class BaseClass<T> {
  property: ReturnType<typeof this.buildProperty>;

  constructor(){
    this.property = this.buildProperty();
  }

  buildProperty(){
    return someBuilder<T>();
  }
}

const test = new BaseClass<number>();
test.property // is number | string
```